# NotSerializableException during serialization of JFrame. Make `JFileChooser` transient to serialization

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jframe, notserializableexception

I wanted to serialize my `JFrame` but unfortunately I get `NotSerializableException`. I thought that the `JFileChoosers` are the reason so I added `transient` modifier to them:
`transient JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");`

**And they are because removing them removes the problem but I need use `JFileChooser` how to make it really transient to serialization?**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class GlowneOkno extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel panelPrawo , panelDol;
    private Okienko panelSr ;
    private final static String[] etykietyFigur = {"Elipsa" , "Kolo" , "Kwadrat" , "Prostokat" , "Trojkat" , "Trojkat Rownoboczny"};
    private static String[] etykietyPrzyciskowKontrolnych = {"Play", "Pause", "Stop"};
    //private JButton playButton, pauseButton, stopButton, elipsaButton, koloButton, kwadratButton, okragButton, prostokatButton, trojkatButton, trojkatRButton;
    private JButton[] przyciskiFigur, przyciskiKontrolne;
    private final static int SIZE = 550;    
    //-------
    private JTabbedPane jtp;
    private MyListModel modelListy; 
    private JList jl;
    private MyListCellRenderer cellRender;

    public GlowneOkno() {
        super("Program");
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        setSize(SIZE + 120, SIZE + 100);
    //  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, SIZE));
        createMenus();
        modelListy = new MyListModel(new ArrayList<>());
         panelSr = new Okienko(modelListy);
         panelDol = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3,50,60));
         panelPrawo = new JPanel();

         ActionListener zmieniaczFigur = new ActionListener() {     
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 JButton jb = (JButton) e.getSource();
                 System.out.println("lkiojgwkjhugfshbkjuidsafhbkfaqwsuki");
                 switch(jb.getText()){
                     case "Elipsa":  ((Okienko) panelSr).setWylosowanaFigura(Okienko.ELIPSA); break;
                     case "Kolo":  ((Okienko) panelSr).setWylosowanaFigura(Okienko.KOLO); break;
                     case "Kwadrat":  ((Okienko) panelSr).setWylosowanaFigura(Okienko.KWADRAT); break;
                     case "Prostokat":  ((Okienko) panelSr).setWylosowanaFigura(Okienko.PROSTOKAT); break;
                     case "Trojkat":  ((Okienko) panelSr).setWylosowanaFigura(Okienko.TROJKAT); break;
                     case "Trojkat /nRownoboczny":  ((Okienko) panelSr).setWylosowanaFigura(Okienko.TROJKAT_ROWNOBOCZNY); break;
                 }
            }
        };
        ActionListener ppsListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 JButton jb = (JButton) e.getSource();
                 switch(jb.getText()){
                 case "Play": ((Okienko) panelSr).playThreads(); break;
                 case "Pause":((Okienko) panelSr).pauseThreads(); break;
                 case "Stop": ((Okienko) panelSr).stopThreads(); break;
                }
            }
        };

        przyciskiFigur = dodajButtony(panelPrawo, przyciskiFigur, etykietyFigur);
        panelPrawo.setLayout(new GridLayout(przyciskiFigur.length , 1));
        add(panelPrawo, BorderLayout.EAST);
        jtp = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
        jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 120));
        przyciskiKontrolne = dodajButtony(panelDol, przyciskiKontrolne, etykietyPrzyciskowKontrolnych);
        dodajListenera(przyciskiKontrolne, ppsListener);

        for(JButton button: przyciskiKontrolne)
            button.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 24));        
        System.out.println(przyciskiFigur.length);
        dodajListenera(przyciskiFigur, zmieniaczFigur);
        jtp.addTab("Kontrola", panelDol);
        add(jtp,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //dodawanie drugiej zakladki---> listy

        jl = new JList(modelListy);
        cellRender = new MyListCellRenderer();
        jl.setCellRenderer(cellRender);


        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
        jsp.getViewport().setView(jl);
        jtp.addTab("Figury", jsp);

        //


        BevelBorder b = new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED);
        panelSr.setBorder(new TitledBorder(b, "Latajace figury"));
        add(panelSr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createMenus() {
        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu jm = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("save");
        JMenuItem load = new JMenuItem("load");

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            transient JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(GlowneOkno.this);      
                   if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                        save(file);
                   }
            }

            private void save(File file) {
                 FileOutputStream fos = null;
                 ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
                 /*
                  * Zapis do strumienia (plikowego, ale może być dowolne)
                  */
                 try {
                   fos= new FileOutputStream(file); //utworzenie strumienia wyjściowego
                   oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);  //utworzenie obiektu zapisującego do strumienia

                   oos.writeObject(GlowneOkno.this); //serializacja obiektu

                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();

                 } finally {
                   // zamykamy strumienie w finally
                   try {
                     if (oos != null) oos.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {}
                   try {
                     if (fos != null) fos.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {}
                 }

            }
        });
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            transient JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(GlowneOkno.this);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                        load(file);
                  }
            }

            private void load(File file) {
                 FileInputStream fis = null;
                 ObjectInputStream ois = null;
                 try {
                   fis = new FileInputStream(file); //utworzenie strumienia wejściowego  
                   ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); //utworzenie obiektu odczytującego obiekty ze strumienia
                   GlowneOkno o = (GlowneOkno) ois.readObject();

            /*     ArrayList<Przesuwacz> wczytanaListaPrzesuwaczy = (ArrayList<Przesuwacz>) ois.readObject();
                   panelSr.setListaPrzesuwaczy(wczytanaListaPrzesuwaczy); //deserializacja obiektu
                   ArrayList<Wyrysowywalny> w = new ArrayList<Wyrysowywalny>();
                   for(Przesuwacz p: wczytanaListaPrzesuwaczy){
                       w.add(p.getF());
                   }
                   panelSr.l = w;
                   System.out.println(w.size() +  " -----------------------------------------");*/
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 } finally {
                   // zasoby zwalniamy w finally
                   try {
                     if (ois != null) ois.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {}
                   try {
                     if (fis != null) fis.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {}
                 }

            }
        });

        jm.add(save); jm.add(load); jmb.add(jm);
        setJMenuBar(jmb);
    }

    private JButton[] dodajButtony(JPanel jp , JButton[] bTab , String[] etykiety ){
        bTab = new JButton[etykiety.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < bTab.length; i++){
            bTab[i] = new JButton(etykiety[i]);
            jp.add(bTab[i]);
        }
        return bTab;
    }

    private void dodajListenera(JButton[] bTab , ActionListener al){
        for(JButton jb : bTab)
            jb.addActionListener(al);   
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GlowneOkno();
    }

}
```

---

**ERRORS**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at GlowneOkno$3.save(GlowneOkno.java:152)
    at GlowneOkno$3.actionPerformed(GlowneOkno.java:138)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

should be this

```
public class GlowneOkno extends JFrame implements Serializable{
```

try it.

Comment: `JFrame` already implements `Serializable` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html